# How can I generate a list of post-type specific categories?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, archives, links

I'm trying to generate a full list of post categories with links based on post type.

So, let's say I'm on an archive page for the custom post type "reports" - when I click on a category link (for example "education") I'd like it to take me to a category archive that only shows posts with a custom post type of "reports" in the "education" category.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template page and use the WP loop: taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Or you can use the get_posts functionality: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters

Something like this maybe:

```
    <?php
      $args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'post_type' => 'reports',
         'my_custom_taxonomy_name' => 'education',
         'post_status' => 'publish'
     );

    $show_albums = get_posts( $args );
    ?>
```

This will return a list of posts in that category, you can then display them on the page.

Comment: Good solution, but wouldn't this require me to create a custom template for every single category?

This is work for a client site, which I won't be maintaining, so if they were to add a new category the functionality wouldn't work for it. Whatever I do needs to be forward compatible so they can manage it on their own.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: That's right, instead of option one `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` you would create the template page `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` which all terms will default too (the WP loop will work out what posts to display) https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Comment: I'm still not quite following - surely running a query on taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php is still a custom category template, isn't it? I'd still have to create taxonomy-education.php and taxonomy-my-category.php for each respective category?

Comment: No, because there aren't any category specific template pages they will default to using the taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php page (the wordpress template hierarchy link I sent shows the fallback template page in order of fallback). So you only need to create one template page, all individual categories will default to use that template. The template will pick up that it should only display posts from the category the user is in automatically within the WP loop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really not getting this. I don't understand how this works for automation purposes. If I have to use the loop or get_posts in that template, to filter my posts according to post_type, I still have to have individual args per category, no? I'm not using a custom taxonomy here. I'm using custom terms within the category taxonomy, and want to return category links (that are added automatically every time a new category is added) that display posts only from a certain post type. I'm really not sure how the above does that.

Comment: Can you confirm what you're trying to do from your original question: 1) Display a list of linkable category terms (there's a widget that does this for the default category taxonomy) or 2) "I'd like it to take me to a category archive that only shows posts with a custom post type of "reports" in the "education" category."

Comment: "If I have to use the loop or get_posts in that template, to filter my posts according to post_type" You don't have to use get posts, just put the default wp loop on the correct template and wordpress will pick up everything else and display the correct posts: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Here is an explanation of how the wordpress default blog/ category works: https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates I would recommend reading this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40953/discussion-between-emily-and-jon-watson).